# How to set the out parameter when using ROW_NUMBER() & COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I set the out @Total parameter of this tsql proc when using the ROW_NUMBER() OVER along with COUNT(*)?

```
    ALTER proc [Generic].[proc_GetPartsForUser_BySupplier_ByCategory]
@UserID      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@SupplierID  INT,
@CategoryID  INT,
@StartIndex  INT, 
@PageSize    INT, 
@Total       INT out
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @StartIndex = @StartIndex + 1
BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM (
             SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNum, COUNT(*) OVER() AS Total
             FROM (
                            SELECT p.*,
                                   s.Name'SupplierName',s.Email'SupplierEmail',s.Phone'SupplierPhone'

                              FROM [Generic].[Part] p  WITH(NOLOCK)                         JOIN
                                   Generic.Supplier s  WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.SupplierID = s.ID

                              WHERE p.ID  IN(SELECT up.PartID FROM Generic.GenericCatalog gc with(nolock) JOIN
                                                Generic.UserPart up WITH(NOLOCK) ON up.GenericCatID = gc.ID
                                                WHERE gc.UserID = @UserID)
                              AND
                              CategoryID = @CategoryID
                              AND
                              s.ID = @SupplierID
            ) AS firstt
            ) AS final
         WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @StartIndex AND (@StartIndex + @pageSize) - 1

            ORDER BY final.[Name] ASC;

END;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Comment: What value do you want to insert into the @Total parameter?

Comment: The OVER() AS Total, I need to set the total number of records available from the OVER() AS Total into the @Total out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't!
The `OVER()` clause creates a windowed function, meaning it will return the value for every row! The parameter can only store one value!

The question remains, why do you want to do this?
If the point of the entire query is to return the value of `COUNT(*)`, then just use it without the `OVER` clause like this:

```
SELECT @Total = COUNT(*) 
FROM   (SELECT p.*, 
               s.NAME 'SupplierName', 
               s.EMAIL'SupplierEmail', 
               s.PHONE'SupplierPhone' 
        FROM   [Generic].[PART] p WITH(NOLOCK) 
               JOIN GENERIC.SUPPLIER s WITH(NOLOCK) 
                 ON p.SUPPLIERID = s.ID 
        WHERE  p.ID IN(SELECT up.PARTID 
                       FROM   GENERIC.GENERICCATALOG gc WITH(NOLOCK) 
                              JOIN GENERIC.USERPART up WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                ON up.GENERICCATID = gc.ID 
                       WHERE  gc.USERID = @UserID) 
               AND CATEGORYID = @CategoryID 
               AND s.ID = @SupplierID) AS firstt
```

If what you need is more than this, edit your question and I'll try to find you a better answer.

Comment: Gidil, I'm paging the records. Isn't that obvious to you?

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com is it not obvious to you that the over() is not effected by the RowNum BETWEEN

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to ask, because I wasn't sure if there was some other way to set the out parameter.